# First time in MVVM and stuck in the IndexOutOfBoundException Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

So, Hey guys I'm newly working with the MVVM, Observer and with Live Data.
Let me describe you on what i'm working, so basically assume i'm working on the app which is for
Mobile Shop and that shop gives the loan to the customers who come to buy the product from there shop.
This is the working off the app

So, i have created the fragment which will get all the details of the products and also the customer details.
Every thing works fine until i reached in the product details section. In the product details section i created
the fields for the product details, which include search bar, spinner and other fields for the price and others.

HERE IS THE SCREENSHOT OF THAT FORM

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQWwW.jpg)

NEXT STEP - The above form you seeing here it cames from the recyclerview adapter as you can see add button on the right corner
of the form. When i press on the add button the same form will generate below this one.

AND THE INDEXING GOES LIKE THIS

The index of the form with add button is - 0
and when click on the add button
The index of the form which generate below is - 1 and with the remove button so that i can remove and form from any index.

HERE IS THE SCREENSHOT OF THAT FOR YOUR EASE

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REHmc.png)

NEXT STEP - Working with the data to get the product details from the api and set on the above forms

NOTE - LET ME INFORM YOU THAT THIS LIST OF PRODUCTS AND SETTING THE DATA ON THE PRODUCT DETAILS FORM IS DONE IN THE ADAPTER
AND I WILL SHOW YOU THE CODE OF THAT BELOW....

1. Assume you have the mutable list of Products like this

```
private val tempList = mutableListOf<Product>()
```

2. Working in the ViewHolder Class of the Adapter

In this section i using binding to get the id of the AutoCompleteTextView widget and i add the doOnTextChanged on the AutoCompleteTextView id

HERE IS THE CODE -

```
binding.search.doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ ->
             productViewModel.getProduct(
                    itemView.context,
                 mapOf(
                     "category" to 0,
                     "brand" to 0,
                     "page" to 0,
                     "search" to text!!,
                     "from" to "create"
                 )
             )

         }
```

and fetch the data on this AutoCompleteTextView Widget from the ProductViewModel (My Model response which contain the Products Data)

3. Next i add the clear function on the tempList of products so that i can clear the data before the observer observe it because i have to set the data
   on the multiple forms if i click on the add button to generate new form for add some other product details

   ```
   tempList.clear()
   ```
4. I added the getObserveable() function to observe the data from the productViewModel Class (My Model response which contain the Products Data)
   So, when i perform Step number 2 than it will observe the data from the productViewModel
5. After that i check the status of the data authenticated or not so, that i can give infotmation on the toast regarding that data available or not

a. Assume when status is authenticated i created the variable named as (val list) and in that   variable i set the list of the products.
which is like this

```
    val list = it.data?.data?.products ?: listOf()
```

b. Next i apply the for loop on that list so that i can get only the product name and the brand name and add the data on the new list called productNameList

```
     private val productNamelist = mutableListOf<String>()
```

c. In the next step i add the whole data from the list of products in the list called named (tempList), you check on the Point number 1 above.

d. Next step i set the data on the AutoCompletetextView Widget as a simple_spinner_dropdown_item with setAdapter() function to show the selected data on it after search

AND HERE'S THE FULL CODE WHICH I EXPLAINED ABOVE

```
binding.search.doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ ->
                productViewModel.getProduct(
                       itemView.context,
                    mapOf(
                        "category" to 0,
                        "brand" to 0,
                        "page" to 0,
                        "search" to text!!,
                        "from" to "create"
                    )
                )

            }
  tempList.clear()
  productViewModel.getObservable().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                when (it.status) {
                    AuthResource.AuthStatus.LOADING -> {
                        binding.autoProgress = true
                    }
                    AuthResource.AuthStatus.AUTHENTICATED -> {
                        
                        val list = it.data?.data?.products ?: listOf()
                        for (li in list) {
                            this.productNamelist.add("${li.productName} Brand: ${li.brand?.brandName} \n")
                        }
                        tempList.addAll(list)
                        binding.search.apply {
                            setAdapter(ArrayAdapter(
                                    itemView.context,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                    productNamelist
                            ))
                        }
                        binding.autoProgress = false
                    }
                    AuthResource.AuthStatus.ERROR -> {
                        session.toast = it.message ?: ""
                        binding.autoProgress = false
                    }
                    AuthResource.AuthStatus.NOT_AUTHENTICATED -> {
                        //Log.e("TAG", "bindData: ${it.message}" )
                        // session.toast = it.message ?: ""
                        binding.autoProgress = false
                    }
                }
            })
```

e. In the next step i apply the setOnClickListener to get the selected position of the product from the AutoCompleteTextView or i can say search bar

HERE'S THE CODE FOR THAT

```
     binding.search.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, pos, _ ->
                try {
                    setAdapter(tempList[pos])
                    Log.e("Search", "Index: ${tempList[pos]}")
                }catch (e:Exception){
                    Log.e("TAG", "bindData: ${e.message}" )
                }

            }
```

Now as you can see in the next step i sended the selected position data to the setAdapter function, so that i can set the data on the spinner on based the selected data from the search bar

f. Next i send the data to the setAdapter() and i sended the full Product object according to the selected position

HERE'S THE CODE FOR THAT

```
     private fun setAdapter(product: Product) {
            Log.e("Product Index", "Data: $product" )
            val varName = mutableListOf<String>()
            val variant = product.variant ?: listOf()
            for (vari in variant) {
                varName.add(vari.colorName ?: "NA")
            }
            binding.variantSpinner.apply {
                adapter =
                    ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, varName)
                setAdapter(adapter)
                onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                    override fun onItemSelected(
                        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                        view: View?,
                        position: Int,
                        id: Long
                    ) {
                        Log.e("Spinner", "Index: $position")
                        val vari = variant[position]
                        Log.e("Variants", "onItemSelected: $vari")
                        binding.cases?.caseProduct?.caseVariant = vari
                        binding.cases?.casePrice = vari.saleAtPrice.toString()
                        binding.cases?.totalAmount = vari.saleAtPrice ?: 0.0
                        binding.cases?.advanceAmount = vari.saleAtPrice ?: 0.0
                        binding.cases?.quantity = "1"
                        binding.variants = variant.get(position)

                        addProduct.onSelect(
                            Soldproduct(
                                0,
                                binding.cases?.caseId?.toInt(),
                                product.brandId,
                                product.categoryId,
                                product.id,
                                vari.id,
                                vari.buyAtPrice ?: 0.0,
                                vari.saleAtPrice ?: 0.0,
                                0.0,

                                vari.serialNumber,
                                vari.modelNumber,
                                vari.hsn,
                                vari.sgst.toString(),
                                vari.cgst.toString(),
                                vari.igst.toString(),
                                1,
                            )
                        )
                        binding.invalidateAll()
                    }
                    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }
                }

            }
 
         }
```

Now let me explained what i did in the above code, as you can see i sended the whole Product Model object as a parameter in the setAdapter(product: Product) function

next i made local list of type String

```
        val varName = mutableListOf<String>()
```

next i fetch the variant details according to the selected product from the search bar above to set in the spinner

```
val variant = product.variant ?: listOf()
```

for example i have product details like this [productName = Redmi Note 10, Price = 12000, Variant = [White,Black,Red,Green]]
and note that the variant is itself a list inside of the list of the products and to set the variants on the spinner i apply the for loop on that

```
        for (vari in variant) {
                varName.add(vari.colorName ?: "NA")
            }
```

and add the data on varName list

after that i set the varName list on the spinner with the help of the setAdapter you can see in the above section f. but i will write some code down here for your ease

```
        binding.variantSpinner.apply {
                adapter =
                    ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, varName)
                setAdapter(adapter)
        
    }
```

after the setting the data on the spinner i apply the onItemSelectedListener, and as the varaint selected i set all the there product detials according to the variant in the product details form fields which added the screen shot above

HERE I'M SETTING THE DATA FOR PRODUCT ACCORDING TO THE VARIANTS

```
        onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                    override fun onItemSelected(
                        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                        view: View?,
                        position: Int,
                        id: Long
                    ) {
                        Log.e("Spinner", "Index: $position")
                        val vari = variant[position]
                        Log.e("Variants", "onItemSelected: $vari")
                        binding.cases?.caseProduct?.caseVariant = vari
                        binding.cases?.casePrice = vari.saleAtPrice.toString()
                        binding.cases?.totalAmount = vari.saleAtPrice ?: 0.0
                        binding.cases?.advanceAmount = vari.saleAtPrice ?: 0.0
                        binding.cases?.quantity = "1"
                        binding.variants = variant.get(position)

                        addProduct.onSelect(
                            Soldproduct(
                                0,
                                binding.cases?.caseId?.toInt(),
                                product.brandId,
                                product.categoryId,
                                product.id,
                                vari.id,
                                vari.buyAtPrice ?: 0.0,
                                vari.saleAtPrice ?: 0.0,
                                0.0,

                                vari.serialNumber,
                                vari.modelNumber,
                                vari.hsn,
                                vari.sgst.toString(),
                                vari.cgst.toString(),
                                vari.igst.toString(),
                                1,
                            )
                        )
                        binding.invalidateAll()
                    }
                    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }
```

Now ater all this my works fine untill at some point my app crashes and gives me the error IndexOutOfBoundExcpetion Error.

Here's how

1. I serach first product and set the data on the spinner and on that case spinner will set the data on the other fields which is works fine
2. When i click on the Add Button on the product Details form it will generate new same form below which i explains earlier. Now from here the things went wrong,because as i search some other products, data fetched normally but cannot set on the form fileds which gives me the IndexOutOfBoundExcpetion here....

In other words i can only be able to set the data once before adding any more products to buy, But i want is that if choose to add more than one product details for single customer, my data will set all of other multiple forms easily....

PLEASE HELP ME OUT HERE, I'M STUCK ON THIS FOR LIKE 4 DAYS AND I SEARCH EVERYTHING BUT I CANNOT BE ABLE TO RESOLVE THIS PROBLEM

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: I appreciate you made effort to describe your problem extensively, but I'm afraid this is just too much for anyone to digest. I guess it is not possible to publish the source code of the whole application, so other people could run it on their computer. Could you provide the stacktrace? In which line exactly does this error occur? Did you try to analyze the situation using the debugger? For example, set a breakpoint in the line that throws exception, see what is the index and what is in the array/list then go back and try to understand what happened.

Comment: It looks like the place where you are setting `tempList[pos]` is throwing the exception, since at `pos` value index, `tempList` doesn't have any data. Somewhere I also saw you are clearing `tempList`. Before accessing any data with some index, check the size of the collection and make sure at the given index data actually exists.

Comment: @Varsha Kulkarni, Varsha is right i'm getting the exception at the time when i set the data for the one more product in t he form and  i also check through the break points and in that case i'm getting the data from the above tempList[pos] and sending to the spinner function without any difficulty and that time exception comes here. It says java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundException: Index:1, Size:1

Comment: @broot thanks for the reply i did what you said and check through the break points and in that case i'm getting the data from the above tempList[pos] and sending to the spinner function without any difficulty and that time exception comes here. It says java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundException: Index:1, Size:1

Comment: As you can see, your `tempList` contains only a single item and you try to acquire the 2nd item. This causes the error. Shouldn't it contain 2 items if you say this happens after you used "Add" button? If so, then add breakpoints or logs everywhere you modify the contents of `tempList` and try to analyze, why it is only 1 and not 2.

Comment: I also noticed potentially (but only potentially) suspicious thing in the code. `tempList` and `productNamelist` seem to be tight to each other. They are created together from the same data. `binding.search` is filled with `productNamelist`, but then it reads data from `tempList`, so it seems these two lists should be always synchronized with each other. The thing is, we see in the code that you clear `tempList`, but you don't clear `productNamelist`. Doesn't that mean `productNamelist` may grow bigger than `tempList`?